# one click open pic and writes the URL to txt file

Tags: php, cgi

Click the link to see the picture. (picture opens) Behind the scenes, the URL for the picture is written in a TXT file on the server..(a html or a xhtml, or html or whatever) A designated file just for the collecting of the URL clicks.

I then can open the TXT file to see what picture someone looked at. The URL will already be written as a link to the picture. I do have the means of erasing the file. Each write of a URL can be placed in the TXT file as needed.

Example:

```
<a href="IntermediatePictures/62TrunkQuarters61.JPG" span onclick="var img = new Image();                   
img.src = 'PrivateCounter/Counter.pl/PrivateView.txt/IntermediatePictures/62TrunkQuarters61.JPG'"></span>
```

This of course, is not a working string. However, assuming the script it's writing to is correct, how would the `href` be structured to open the picture, then behind the scenes write the clicked URL to the TXT file? - Assuming the `Counter.pl` script is written correctly.

If anyone has a php script that can do this that would be great too. Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: Sounds like you have a great plan. All others just follow the mainstream stuff like Google analytics and such, but your a pioneer building your own stuff with high end txt files.

Answer (score 0):

So, depending on the link, lets say its http://www.yourdomain.com/IntermediatePictures/62TrunkQuarters61.JPG

```
$txt = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $myfile = file_put_contents('Counter.pl', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Or maybe you'll need www.yourdomain.com/somepage?picture=62TrunkQuarters61.JPG

then:

```
$txt = $_GET['picture'];
 $myfile = file_put_contents('Counter.pl', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```